# How to move a file located outside the public folder?

Tags: php, laravel

I am right now trying to figure out how I can move a file that got temporarily stored in storage/app/chunks to a public folder in order to save it there permanently.

I have tried

```
$chunk_file_path = "/storage/app/chunks/The Simpsons Movie - 1080p Trailer.mp4-YMtmuO4cEG4ejK6knZOEzZCxVie0NwDgdFqggThG-147399359.part";
$chunk_move_path = "uploads/The Simpsons Movie - 1080p Trailer.mp4-YMtmuO4cEG4ejK6knZOEzZCxVie0NwDgdFqggThG-147399359.part";
Storage::move($chunk_file_path, $chunk_move_path);
```

The problem I encounter is

`FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php line 385:
File not found at path: storage/app/chunks/The Simpsons Movie - 1080p Trailer.mp4-YMtmuO4cEG4ejK6knZOEzZCxVie0NwDgdFqggThG-147399359.part`

The file does exist, but it seems like root folder is automatically the public folder of the Laravel installation. So it is looking in `public/storage/app/chunks/The Simpsons Movie - 1080p Trailer.mp4-YMtmuO4cEG4ejK6knZOEzZCxVie0NwDgdFqggThG-147399359.part` and can't find it obviously, because it is not in the public folder hierarchy.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `config/filesystems.php` and either 1) modify your `public` settings, or create a new setting and pass it into `Storage::disk('new_setting')->move($chunk_file_path, $chunk_move_path);`

Such as:

```
'disks' => [
    'videos' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => '/some/path/here', // (I recommend still using `storage_path()` here
    ]
]
```

`Storage::disk('videos')->move($chunk_file_path, $chunk_move_path)`

See the Laravel documentation for [Filesystems](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#configuration) for more information (including making the files publicly accessible).

Comment: Thanks! Because it is saved on two different disks, is there a way I could transfer it from the "chunks" disk to the "videos" disk?

Comment: Great, I am using public_path() and storage_path() thanks for pointing them out!